# Transformar string em array

Tags: javascript

Estou pesquisando dados e montando uma string para passar para o api de gráficos do google porém estou tendo problema, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
var variavel = "['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes'],";
for(var b = 0; b < pontos.length; b++){
    var obj = pontos[b][0];
    variavel = variavel + "['" + obj.data + "', " + obj.membros + ", " + obj.visitantes + "],"
   }

   variavel = variavel.replace(/'/g, '"');

   var parsVal = JSON.parse(variavel);
```

Nesta parte estou criando esta string.

O problema que está dando é por causa da `,` na ultima vez que ele passa no for.
No console ficou plotado o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Depois disto estou fazendo é plotar na div o gráfico:

```
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsVal);

    var options = {
     title: 'Membros x Visitantes',
     curveType: 'function',
     legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

Meu gráfico não está aparecendo na página.

Na documentação esta mandando eu fazer deste jeito:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

porém o que eu preciso é faze-lo de forma dinâmica, a pega os dados ao ser carregado a página. Este gráfico estou pegando aqui:

```
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart
```

Comment: Acho que o problema está antes disso tudo, no trecho `var variavel = "['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes'],";`. Nesse trecho poderia já deixar formatado como um array Javascript e inclusive está quase lá.. rsrs.. Presuponho que esse dado vem de alguma outra linguagem, certo? (php, asp, etc..).. E observando a vírgula sobrando no final já percebe-se que está bem desleixado.. Por isso acredito que a sua questão nem existiria se esse trecho fosse bem feito.

Comment: @DanielOmine este dado é colocado por mim porque se observar vc verá que é necessario ter isto dentro do array, e isto é o primeiro dado a que se deve passar. E os dados não vem de outra linguagem, estou pegando ele no localStorage e iterando ele desta forma.

Comment: De curiosidade, qual é o sentido de trabalhar com strings? Seria muito mais fácil usar objetos nativos do que ficar convertendo e desconvertendo, não? Montar uma string pra depois fazer parse me dá uma impressão ruim (mas se tiver uma razão legítima pra fazer isso, e puder comentar, talvez eu entenda melhor o código).

Comment: @Bacco na verdade isto foi uma solução que encontrei, eu sei que preciso passar isto para meu gráfico, teria uma outra forma de fazer ? colocarei o que esta no site de como deve ser.

Comment: no localstorage poderia já guardar esses dados no formato json.. aí facilitaria as coisas... não teria esse problema em ter que converter nem nada.. Então o problema está aí, na forma como salva os dados no localstorage

Comment: Meu localStorage trabalha como um banco de dados normal, tenho nele varias tabelas que identifico com um sufixo exemplo_, neste caso tenho vários dados, estes dados são calculado toda vez que entro em minha aplicação, assim eu guardo na tabela, que horas fiz, a quantidade de membros e de visitantes, para posteriormente pegar no gráfico, o problema está ocorrendo quando estou mandando este array para api do google, pois preciso pesquisar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No seu caso, usar *string* é um passo desnecessário, pois você pode usar objetos do JS mesmo para obter o resultado desejado.

Com base nisso, segue uma simplificação do seu código original:

```
var variavel = [['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes']];
for(var b = 0; b < pontos.length; b++){
    var obj = pontos[b][0];
    variavel.push( [ obj.data, obj.membros, obj.visitantes ] );
}
```

desta forma, `variavel` já conterá o objeto pronto, sem conversão.

Pra entender melhor, começamos criando um *array* de *array*:

```
var variavel = [['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes']];
```

e aqui, simplesmente colocamos a cada iteração um novo array de 3 itens no principal:

```
    variavel.push( [ obj.data, obj.membros, obj.visitantes ] );
```

Supondo que `data`, `membros` e `visitantes` sejam respectivamente 1, 2 e 3 na primeira iteração e 10, 20 e 30 na segunda, fica assim a variável:

```
[
   ['Data', 'Membros', 'Visitantes'],
   [      1,        2,            3],
   [     10,       20,           30]
]
```

e assim sucessivamente.

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/jAaLxY?editors=0010)**.

Comment: resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! Qualquer duvida avise, é legal vc entender o que foi feito, pq pode melhorar sua pratica em JS.

Comment: eu entendo que foi feito, porém esta desatento, estava misturando duas ideias. Agora estou tendo problemas com atualizar um gráfico ja existente, manja sobre isto ?

Comment: Nunca usei essa API, mas me parece o caso de abrir uma pergunta em separado com o código funcional, e explicar o que quer fazer.